# Conexión con CIFS (smb) en Android

Tags: android

Tengo un código realizado en Java donde me conecto al servidor CIDS (smb) dentro de la misma red.

Quiero hacer lo mismo, pero desde Android. Importé la librería **jcifs 1.3.19** y al parecer todo marcha bien. El problema está en cuanto mi método `conectar` quiere ver los archivos dentro, éste no los muestra.

El código de conexión es el siguiente:

```
public void conecta(View v){
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth=new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("","alumno", "alumno");
    try {
        SmbFile smbFile=new SmbFile("smb://192.168.0.10/alumno_compartido/",auth);
        for (SmbFile f : smbFile.listFiles()){
            if(f.isFile()){
                String temp=""+f.getName();
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException | SmbException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Pero al querer ejecutar esa función la aplicación me pide reiniciar y me sale el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.draw_prueba, PID: 9303
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
```

Pero si le quito la parte donde intento hacer algo con `smbFile` funciona correcto. Por ejemplo, si el código luce de la siguiente manera:

```
public void conecta(View v){
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth=new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("","alumno", "alumno");
    try {
        SmbFile smbFile=new SmbFile("smb://192.168.0.10/alumno_compartido/",auth);
    } catch (MalformedURLException | SmbException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tengo los siguientes permisos en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Ese error se puede producir porque tengas una errata en el XML, asegúrate de que donde pusiste `android:onClick="conecta"` no pone conecta**r** o algo así.

Comment: ¿Has probado a quitar `System.out.println(temp);` y usar en su lugar `Log.i(temp);`? Recuerda que no estás en java de símbolo de sistema :)

Comment: En realidad el System.out.println() no me genera ningun error. Pero si lo que intento es solo ejecutar SmbFile[] lista= smbFile.listFiles(); en lugar del for es donde deja de funcionar.

Comment: ¿Has probado mi última edición? Aunque debería soportar sin problemas la sintaxis del for-each, por descartar y poder depurar (se puede poner, por ejemplo, un `Log.i("MiApp", f.length);` para depurar el tamaño del resultado).

Comment: Si, pero aun me marca el mismo error. No se si falta agregar algún permiso a la aplicación. Por el lado de Solaris, que es mi servidor, no tiene problemas con conectarse con mi código java ejecutado desde consola.

Comment: ¿Ese es el volcado de pila completo? ¿Podrías agregar un grupo de captura genérico? Edité mi respuesta para indicarte cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cambiar en tu código la llamada a [`System.out.println(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) por una versión equivalente en Android como [`Log.i(String, String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log?hl=es#i(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
public void conecta(View v) {
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
        "",
        "alumno",
        "alumno"
    );
    try {
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(
           "smb://192.168.0.10/alumno_compartido/",
           auth
        );
        for (SmbFile f : smbFile.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                Log.i("MiAppArchivos", f.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException | SmbException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Además, te recomendaría no hacer este tipo de tareas en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario.

Nota: no estoy seguro, pero quizá también tengas que cambiar la manera de iterar los elementos:

```
public void conecta(View v) {
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
        "",
        "alumno",
        "alumno"
    );
    try {
        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(
           "smb://192.168.0.10/alumno_compartido/",
           auth
        );
        SmbFile[] f = smbFile.listFiles();
        for (int n = 0; n < f.length; n++) {
            if (f[n].isFile()) {
                Log.i("MiAppArchivos", f[n].getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MiAppArchivos", "Excepción capturada", e);
    }
}
```

Además de cambiar el método de iterar, también he cambiado la captura de cualquier tipo de excepción.